# Unsupported lookup 'iexect' for CharField or join on the field not permitted

Tags: python, django

Could anyone tell me why I get a FieldError?

```
class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=35, label="Username
eintragen")
    password = forms.CharField(min_length=6, max_length=50, label="Password eintragen", widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    email = forms.EmailField(label="Email eintragen")

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
        if User.objects.filter(username__iexect=username).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("Diesen Usernamen gibt es schon")
        return username
```

Error:

> Unsupported lookup 'iexect' for CharField or join on the field not permitted.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I'd recommend fixing your [code formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189) for your first block of code to make it more readable.

Comment: You have a typo. `iexect` should be `iexact`.

Comment: I really appreciate your advices. Sorry for bothering you guys with this newbie stuff.

Comment: Ah no problem, everyone was new here sometime